# How to optimize httpwebrequest call performance

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, optimization, httpwebrequest

Currently I'm building a c# based desktop application. Its like a small web form auto filler. The application make GET and POST calls for getting the images in responsestream. But I'm getting very slow response. Any suggestions on how I can increase the speed of image download. Following is the code for downloading the image and POST call

Image Download Function:

```
public void download_image(string go_to_url, string referer)
    {                             
        this.httpWebRequest_cls_1 = null;        
        HttpWebResponse response = null;        
        try
        {            
            this.httpWebRequest_cls_1 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(go_to_url);
                this.httpWebRequest_cls_1.Proxy = null;
                WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = null;
            HttpRequestCachePolicy policy = new HttpRequestCachePolicy(HttpRequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore);
            this.httpWebRequest_cls_1.ServicePoint.UseNagleAlgorithm = false;
            this.httpWebRequest_cls_1.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
            this.httpWebRequest_cls_1.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = 100000;
            this.httpWebRequest_cls_1.ServicePoint.ConnectionLeaseTimeout = 65000;
            this.httpWebRequest_cls_1.ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime = 100000;            
            this.httpWebRequest_cls_1.CookieContainer = global_store.cookieContainer_0;
            this.httpWebRequest_cls_1.Referer = str1;
            this.httpWebRequest_cls_1.KeepAlive = true;            
            this.httpWebRequest_cls_1.ReadWriteTimeout = 0xc350;
            this.httpWebRequest_cls_1.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";                                              
            this.httpWebRequest_cls_1.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip,deflate");            
            this.httpWebRequest_cls_1.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.65 Safari/537.36";            
            this.httpWebRequest_cls_1.UnsafeAuthenticatedConnectionSharing = true;
            this.httpWebRequest_cls_1.AuthenticationLevel = System.Net.Security.AuthenticationLevel.None;                                    
            this.httpWebRequest_cls_1.PreAuthenticate = true;
            this.httpWebRequest_cls_1.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
            this.httpWebRequest_cls_1.Pipelined = false;
            this.httpWebRequest_cls_1.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
            this.httpWebRequest_cls_1.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            this.httpWebRequest_cls_1.Headers.Set("Cache-Control", "max-age=86400");
            this.httpWebRequest_cls_1.ContentLength = 0L;
            this.httpWebRequest_cls_1.Method = "GET";
            response = (HttpWebResponse)this.httpWebRequest_cls_1.GetResponse();            
            global_store.image_0 = Image.FromStream(response.GetResponseStream());
            staticstore.get_cap_time = new TimeSpan(DateTime.Now.Hour, 

DateTime.Now.Minute, DateTime.Now.Second);            
    }
    catch (WebException exception)
    {
        string exp = exception.ToString();            
    }        
    finally
    {           
        if (response != null)
        {
            response.Close();
            response = null;
        }
        if (this.httpWebRequest_cls_1 != null)
        {
            this.httpWebRequest_cls_1.Abort();
            this.httpWebRequest_cls_1 = null;
        }
    }                
}
```

POST Request Sending Function:

```
public string simple_web_call(string go_to, string from, string params_to_post, string conditions)
    {
        string str = "";
        string responseHeader = "";
        httpWebRequest_3 = null;
        Stream requestStream = null;
        HttpWebResponse response = null;
        Stream responseStream = null;
        try
        {
            this.httpWebRequest_3 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(go_to));
            HttpRequestCachePolicy policy = new HttpRequestCachePolicy(HttpRequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore);
            this.httpWebRequest_3.CachePolicy = policy;            
            this.httpWebRequest_3.Proxy = null;
            WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = null;            
            this.httpWebRequest_3.ServicePoint.UseNagleAlgorithm = false;
            this.httpWebRequest_3.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
            this.httpWebRequest_3.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = 65000;
            this.httpWebRequest_3.ServicePoint.ConnectionLeaseTimeout = Class9.int_7;
            this.httpWebRequest_3.ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime = 10000;
            this.httpWebRequest_3.CookieContainer = Class28.cookieContainer_0;
            this.httpWebRequest_3.Referer = from;
            this.httpWebRequest_3.KeepAlive = true;
            this.httpWebRequest_3.Connection = "keepalive";
            this.httpWebRequest_3.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
            this.httpWebRequest_3.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows T 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36";            
            this.httpWebRequest_3.Headers.Set("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            this.httpWebRequest_3.UnsafeAuthenticatedConnectionSharing = true;
            this.httpWebRequest_3.AuthenticationLevel = System.Net.Security.AuthenticationLevel.None;
            this.httpWebRequest_3.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;            
            this.httpWebRequest_3.Headers.Set("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            if (params_to_post != "")
            {
                this.httpWebRequest_3.Method = "POST";
                byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(params_to_post);
                this.httpWebRequest_3.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                this.httpWebRequest_3.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
                requestStream = this.httpWebRequest_3.GetRequestStream();
                requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                requestStream.Flush();
                requestStream.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                this.httpWebRequest_3.Method = "GET";
            }
            response = (HttpWebResponse)this.httpWebRequest_3.GetResponse();
            HttpWebResponse response2 = response;
            switch (response2.StatusCode)
            {
                case HttpStatusCode.OK:
                    {
                        responseStream = response2.GetResponseStream();
                        str = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8).ReadToEnd();                        
                        responseStream.Close();
                        responseStream = null;
                        goto flush_all;

                    }
                case HttpStatusCode.MovedPermanently:
                case HttpStatusCode.Found:
                case HttpStatusCode.SeeOther:
                case HttpStatusCode.TemporaryRedirect:
                    responseHeader = response2.GetResponseHeader("Location");
                    if (!responseHeader.Contains("err")) { break; }
                    str = "retry";
                    goto flush_all;
                default:
                    str = "retry";
                    goto flush_all;
            }
            str = responseHeader;
        flush_all:
            response2 = null;
            response.Close();
            response = null;
            this.httpWebRequest_3 = null;
            if (str == "") { str = "retry"; }
        }
        catch (WebException exception)
        {
            string exp = exception.ToString();            
        }
        finally
        {
            if (requestStream != null)
            {
                requestStream.Close();
                requestStream.Dispose();
                requestStream = null;
            }
            if (responseStream != null)
            {
                responseStream.Close();
                responseStream.Dispose();
                responseStream = null;
            }
            if (response != null)
            {
                response.Close();
                response = null;
            }
            if (this.httpWebRequest_3 != null)
            {
                this.httpWebRequest_3.Abort();
                this.httpWebRequest_3 = null;
            }
        }
        return str;
    }
```

Comment: Give is more source code, it's not enough 

Comment: Do you want me to add all source code of my application? The main code of the application resides in both of above function posted.

Comment: Haha, no. It was just ironic.

Comment: You can use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)  to see the actual timings and responses between your client and the server. I expect the server to respond slowly.